# grails log4j is not working on custom appenders

Tags: grails, log4j

I am trying to log the "info and above level" logging from grails.app.controllers and grails.app.services into this appender "appLog". From the documentation and a lot of google search and ofcourse stack overflow. I understood that all i need is my appender and then logger info.
But that never works for me, so i added the root block as below and made it route every log to my appender and I also set my additivity to false so that it won't pull any of the inherited logs.
My requirement was very simple, but i could not get it working. I am using grails 2.4.1.

Can someone please shed some light on what is going wrong here?

Below is my configuration:

```
Log4j:main{
    appender name: "appLog",
        new org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender(
            threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO,
            datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
            file: log4jFileName,
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '[%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS}] %p %c{5} %m%n')
        )

    info additivity: false, appLog: "grails.app.services.xxxService"

    root {
        debug 'appLog'
        additivity = false 
    }

}
```

Comment: Is all of this in a log4j closure in Config.groovy? Meaning `log4j = { ... }`. The `Log4J:main` part of your configuration is throwing me off.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Yes, log4j block is in my config.groovy class. By default the last block was called log4j.main = {...} this had some commented out code which i replaced it with the code i had pasted in the question..

Comment: Is your appender in an `appenders` block? See [the appenders section of the logging doc](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging).

Comment: Thank you so much.That was a stupid mistake.I was trying out almost all combinations to get this working and I removed that block. My bad. Now i can see the logs i enter in my service class in my custom appender. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things I'm seeing wrong here:

1. Your `name: "appLog"` portion should be inside of the `DailyRollingFileAppender` constructor.
2. You are missing an appenders block.

Try changing the configuration to this:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        appender new org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender(
            name: "appLog",
            threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO,
            datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
            file: log4jFileName,
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '[%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS}] %p %c{5} %m%n')
        )
    }

    info additivity: false,
         appLog: "grails.app.services.xxxService"

    root {
        debug 'appLog'
    }
}
```